# How can i make installer which install python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, installation, install-forge

I made a simple selenium script. I want make installer for this script which will install python3.9 on PC. I use InstallForge where I can call commands in cmd. I thought that exist command wchich install python but I didn't found it. How can i make installer which install python?

Comment: How is this question related to _Selenium_?

Comment: no idea but https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ ---> PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package. The user can run the packaged app without installing a Python interpreter or any modules. PyInstaller supports Python 3.6 or newer, and correctly bundles the major Python packages such as numpy, PyQt, Django, wxPython, and others.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.